# Camera not working in opencv but does on libcamera

Tags: python, linux, opencv, raspberry-pi, camera

New to this

Installed
Picamera2
Opencv
Numpy

Have x219 camera with motorized focus
It works with libcamera ( libcamrea-hello and sorts) but when i run a code .py or try and use VideoCapture() in cv2 it cant find  'controls' import error no idear everything sez installed to lastest version... any help thanks

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/leddy/leddycode/code/cass.py", line 13, in <module>
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) /tmp/pip-wheel-u79916uk/opencv-python_ea2489746b3a43bfb3f2b5331b7ab47a/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cvtColor'
```

also i get this track back from opening the (python3 AutofocusTest.py -i 10)

```
from libcamera import ControlType, Size, Rectangle
ImportError: cannot import name 'ControlType' from 'libcamera' (/home/leddy/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/libcamera.cpython-39-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so)
```

they are the two errors i have when im trying to use camera
does work with libcamera but with one warn listed below

```
leddy@Leddypie:~ $ libcamera-hello
Made X/EGL preview window
[0:00:42.276441121] [1300]  INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp:293 libcamera v0.0.0+3866-0c55e522
[0:00:42.331671047] [1301]  WARN RPI raspberrypi.cpp:1258 Mismatch between Unicam and CamHelper for embedded data usage!
[0:00:42.333703436] [1301]  INFO RPI raspberrypi.cpp:1374 Registered camera /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/imx219@10 to Unicam device /dev/media3 and ISP device /dev/media1
[0:00:42.335808584] [1300]  INFO Camera camera.cpp:1035 configuring streams: (0) 1640x1232-YUV420
[0:00:42.337020047] [1301]  INFO RPI raspberrypi.cpp:761 Sensor: /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/imx219@10 - Selected sensor format: 1640x1232-SBGGR10_1X10 - Selected unicam format: 1640x1232-pBAA
leddy@Leddypie:~ $
```

[image]

Comment: OpenCV requires the thing to be exposed as `/dev/video*`, through V4L/V4L2. if you can't do that, you can't use `cv::VideoCapture`

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: iv put trace in thanks

Comment: Did u add config.txt?

Comment: Yes .. i reloaded bullseye 11 and used the adrucam install page for lmx219 and it will now run the focuserExsample .py ao it works and libcamer works but now there is no dection=0 and it still wont work in cv2.vcap()

Comment: Its has img= none ret = false so i geuss its not getting anything from camera i think iv installed the v42l drivers works with picamera2 as well

Comment: Its the cvtcolor error everyone getting but its because it has no image to load so it fails there but the problem is no feed or controls set

Comment: Did u set this? dtoverlay=imx219 and camera_auto_detect=0

Comment: If u have webcam, it will worked.

Comment: Yer any help is good

Comment: My mistaken. Can u post the code. So I can try my RPi 4B?